# Xamarin Forms Bind List<myObject> to Picker

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I created this Picker:

```
<Picker SelectedIndex="0" x:Name="pickerMode" Margin="30,0,30,0" />
```

And in my background code I set the ItemSource like this:

```
List<Mode> modeList = new List<Mode>();
Mode mode = new Mode
{
    Id = 0,
    Name = "Item1",
    Type = "Test"
}

modeList.Add(mode)
pickerMode.ItemsSource = modeList;
```

But when I launch the App, the picker stays empty.
I want the Picker to show the Name of every Mode in that List.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this property in the XAML on your Picker `ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"`